# How to extract (alphabet+number+underscore) string before and aftter the dots using reg exp

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a quick way using reg exp in PHP to extract what is before and after the dots. I might use the explode but it will take long processing.

Sample string:

```
$line = 'var init=new class.init(object.color, object.arrayElements);';
```

I need to get and replace: class, init, object, color, object, arrayElements

I am the trying the below expression which gets words before a vertical dots (:) but it doesn't work in the case of the single dot!

```
$result = preg_match_all('/[a-z0-9_]+(?=\s*.)/i', $line, $output);
```

Your hints are greatly appreciated - Sorry I didn't find any answer by search :(

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\.(\w+)/', $line, $out);
```

Would give you *word-characters* connected to period, where `\w` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. [Modifier i](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) for case-insensitive is not necessaray as `\w` contains *upper* and *lower* already.

```
echo "<pre>";

// [0] full matches
print_r($out[0]);

// [1] \w+ before period
print_r($out[1]);

// [2] \w+ after period
print_r($out[2]);

echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Superb solution! But would you please tell me how can I extract what is before or after the dot in case there is a space, like object . color? Thanks!

Comment: @moderns Use `\s` for white-spaces of any kind e.g. `'/(\w+)\s*\.\s*(\w+)/'` where `\s` is a shorthand for `[ \t\r\n\f]` or only spaces e.g. `'/(\w+) *\. *(\w+)/'`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! You provided excellent solution with a brilliant clarifications! Ton of thanks!

Comment: @moderns Glad, that I could be of help :)